# chart.js disable opacity-animation for tooltip

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

I have a chart, in which I draw some metadata in `animation.onComplete`:

```
animation: {
  onComplete: ChartHelper.barChartDrawMetadata(28, 2)
}
```

When hovering over the chart, a tooltip with extra information shows. But the opacity of this tooltip is animated, 400ms. (I found this in chart.esm.js).

During the tooltip's animation, the drawn metadata is removed, and redraws *after* the tooltip's animation has completed.

I would like to make the animationDuration of the tooltip 0, so that the metadata redraws immediately when the tooltip shows, and is not gone for 400ms at a time.
How would I go about this, if it is even possible?

I tried many things, like setting `plugins.tooltip.animation.duration = 0`, or `plugins.tooltip.animationDuration = 0`, etc.

Now the only way I see is editing the value that is set in chart.esm.js, but I don't see any way to access/override this value.

```
animations: {
  numbers: {
    type: 'number',
    properties: ['x', 'y', 'width', 'height', 'caretX', 'caretY'],
  },
  opacity: {
    easing: 'linear',
    duration: 200
  }
}
```

Is there any documented way to disable the tooltip animation, or not hide the metadata?